# Project Euler #4 - Largest Palindrome Product

Tags: c++, c++11, programming-challenge, palindrome

Problem Statement:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

This code is in C++ 11, please review my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int palindrom(int num);

int main()
{
    auto n1 = 999u;
    auto n2 = 999u;
    unsigned int n = 0u;

    unsigned int largest = 0;

    for (; n1>=100; n2--)
    {
        if (n2 < 100)
        { 
            n1--; 
            n2 = 999; 
            continue; 
        }

        if (palindrom(n1*n2) == n1*n2)
        {
            cout << "n1 << " << n1 << " n2 " << n2 << endl;
            cout << n1*n2;

            if (largest < n1*n2)
                largest = n1*n2;
        }
    }

    cout << "Largest" << largest << endl;

    return 0;
}

int palindrom(int num)
{
    int new_num = 0;
    int digit = 0;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        digit = num % 10;
        new_num = new_num*10 + digit;
        num /= 10;
    }

    return new_num;
}
```

Output (project Euler solution kept secret)

> 906609

Comment: Note this meta post concerning this question: [Keeping 'Competitive Results' private](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/keeping-competitive-results-private)

Comment: @rolfl Thanks for posting. Next time I will not add output in question. Secondly, I think Project Euler sort of sites are for self improvement, and you can harm yourself if you are cheating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The way you've constructed your loop is awkward and hard to reason about.

   Why not just use a pair of nested loops?

   ```
   for(int i=100; i<1000; ++i) {
       for(int j=i; j<1000; ++j) {
           ...do stuff with (i,j)...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Don't use unsigned values unless you really need them.
3. I'd make `palindrome()` into a boolean predicate personally:

   ```
   bool is_palindrome(int n) { ... }
   ```
4. Don't recalculate the value of `n1*n2` over and over again, assign it to a named variable and refer to that. It makes your code more readable & reduces the opportunity for errors to creep in.

Comment: Note that (d) is really about reducing the opportunity for errors to creep into your code. It's better to assign n1*n2 to a suitably named variable & use that everywhere that you need it. That way you know you've used the same value everywhere and make the code more readable at the same time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, (c). Are you taking about overloading `() operator`

Comment: A function named `palindrome()` sounds like it should return `true` if it is a palindrome and `false` if it isn't. A function named `reverse()` has no such connotation. If you keep the name `palindrome()`, then make it test for whether the parameter is a palindrome.

Comment: Exactly. Let me clarify the comment.

Comment: Since multiplication is commutative you can also avoid half of that loop (it even makes the code 2 digits shorter!)

Comment: I did point that out in the comment :) Maybe it would be clearer just to do it.

Comment: "b) Don't use unsigned values unless you really need them." I disagree strongly. Signed integers may overflow with undefined behavior, but unsigned integers don't, which is a plus. Second, the range of unsigned integers is twice as large, hence it may be necessary to use `int64_t` instead of `int32_t`, but `uint32_t` may be sufficient. Yes, one has to be careful with unsigned integers (preventing unintentional overflow), but it's definitively not strictly worse than signed integers.

Comment: @stefan The range of signed integers is exactly as large as the range of unsigned integers. It just doesn't start at zero.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Well yes, but I guess you already got what I meant to say: the size of the positive range (and in this problem we only want positive numbers) is roughly twice as large for unsigned counterparts.

Answer (score 8):

Your function `palindrom` just "reverses" your number without actually checking it is a palindrom. It would probably be more appropriate to give this function a proper name like `reverse_number()` and to use it in a different function which can be called `is_palindrome()`.

Please note that a faster implementation for this could be done differently as one could stop as soon as 2 digits do not match but we can consider that this is good enough: it's easy to test and it's easy to understand how it works.

Also, you could get rid of the magic number `10`. You could for instance provide the base with a default argument.

You should always try to define your variable in the smallest possible scope.

Here's what I have for the helper function :

```
int reverse_number(int num, int base = 10)
{
    int new_num = 0;

    while (num != 0)
    {
        int digit = num % base;
        new_num = new_num*base + digit;
        num /= base;
    }
    return new_num;
}

bool is_palindrom(int num)
{
    return num == reverse_number(num);
}
```

---

You should compile your code with all warnings activated as they can provide you good hints :

```
euler3.cpp:28:18: warning: unused variable ‘n’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

---

The way you are iterating is super weird. If you want to iterate over a range with `n1` and iterate over another range with `n2`, just use two nested for loops:

```
for (auto n1 = 999u; n1>=100; n1--)
for (auto n2 = 998u; n2>=100; n2--)
```

Also, without any loss of generality, one can assume that `n1 >= n2` :

```
for (auto n1 = 999u; n1>=100; n1--)
for (auto n2 = n1;   n2>=100; n2--)
```

---

Because the values will get smaller, you can break when you find a value smaller that the one you have already found.

At the stage, my code looks like:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int largest = 0;

    for (auto n1 = 999u; n1>=100; n1--)
    {
        for (auto n2 = n1;   n2>=100; n2--)
        {
            auto prod = n1*n2;
            if (prod < largest)
                break;

            if (is_palindrom(prod))
            {
                cout << "n1 << " << n1 << " n2 " << n2 << " -> " << prod << endl;
                largest = prod;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Largest" << largest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a variable for n2 limit (`n2>=n2_limit`) and set it to n2 when we find a palindrom?

Comment: It could probably do the trick but I am not quite sure I see the benefit compared to my solution.

Comment: I like the `break` in the inner loop. If you change the inner loop limits so that `n2` goes from 999 down to `n1`, you would probably find the largest palindrome sooner and make the `break` even more effective.

Answer (score 3):

`n` is an unused variable.  Your compiler should have warned you about it (and you should compile with warnings enabled).

Declaring variables with `auto` and an unsigned integer literal is unconventional.  Just `int n1 = 999` would have been more readable.

Your for-loop is weird.  The three fields of a for-loop header should clearly state how the loop behaves.  Testing for `n1 >= 100` while decrementing `n2`, then having a separate test for `n2 < 100` that decrements `n1` and resets `n2` is a really convoluted way of writing a nested for-loop!

Since `n1` and `n2` are symmetric, you can cut the work in half by making the inner loop condition `n2 >= n1` instead of `n2 >= 100`.

`palindrom()` would be better named `reverse()` or `reverse_digits()`.

Testing whether the product exceeds the largest palindrome so far is cheaper than testing whether the product is a palindrome, so do the cheaper test first.

```
#include <iostream>
// You don't need <math.h>

int reverse(int num)
{
    int new_num = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        int digit = num % 10;     // Move the declaration inside the loop
        new_num = new_num * 10 + digit;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return new_num;
}

int main()
{
    int largest = 0;
    for (int n1 = 999; n1 >= 100; n1--)
    {
        for (int n2 = 999; n2 >= n1; n2--)
        {
            int product = n1 * n2;
            if (product > largest && reverse(product) == product)
            {
                largest = product;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Largest " << largest << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. One query why. `int digit = num % 10;` in loop, why shoul I not declare variable only once?

Comment: Declaring the variable inside a loop does _not_ make it any less efficient. It just makes it more tightly scoped so that it is only accessible from inside the loop. That makes it easier to maintain the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `while` loop instead of this:

> ```
> for(; n1>=100; n2--)
> ```

It would look cleaner like this:

```
while(n1 >= 100) {
    // ... some code here
    n2--;
}
```